# How to pass table name as parameter with msnodesqlv8?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

EDIT:
I have two DBs on separate servers (one using MySql and another using MSSQL), I can't modify these tables. On each DB there are multiple corresponding tables that need to be synced according to some rules. What I need to do is for each table in DB1, pull flagged rows, and insert or update them in the appropriate tables on DB2.
I have some queries for pulling the rows, and I want to apply them to each table in DB1. For this, one of the things that I want to do is to be able to dynamically pass a table name.

I do this for field names:

```
var myFirstInput = "foo bar";
var mySecondInput = "hello world";

sql.input('inputField1', sql.VarChar, myFirstInput);
sql.input('inputField2', sql.VarChar, mySecondInput);

sql.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = @inputField1 OR field2 = @inputField2")
.then(function(results)
{
    //do whatever you want with the results
    console.log(results)
})
.catch(function(error)
{
   //do whatever when you get an error
   console.log(error)
})
```

How can I achieve the same for table names?
doing the same with

```
ql.query("SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE someField = 2")
```

won't work

Comment: You can't replace an object name with a variable; it *must* be a literal. Normally, however, such a requirement means a design flaw. Why do you want to do this? If you "must" you have to use dynamic SQL and **securely** inject the dynamic object name(s), but if it's a design issue fixing the design is *always* a far better option.

Comment: @Larnu I'm parsing multiple tables with the same queries. I do it with MySQL ?? placeholder all the time. What's the alternative? having queries for each table? it's very unrealistic

Comment: It's not unrealistic at all. If you have tables with the same design, as this type of requirement normally implies, then the problem is the design as you are using the table's name to infer information that should be stored as a column. For example, having a table per company, instead of a single table with a column `company` that you can then use a parametrised query against. It's actually unrealistic to have multiple tables with the same design as it doesn't scale.

Comment: @Larnu I think I didn't explain myself well enough. I have exactly what you are describing, do I need to place the table name in a literal instead of a variable? it still doesn't work, I think my problem is in the syntax for msnodesqlv8, I just can't find it

Comment: No, fix your design; again don't have one table per company, have one table with a `company` column. Then you can simply parametrise your query with `WHERE Company = ?`. Easy. The problem *isn't* Node.js, as you *can't* parametrise an object name it *must* be a literal. Fixing your design will eliminate the problem as it won't exist. This is what we call an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu I think we're both misunderstanding each other and getting into a spin. I'm quite a beginner so I'm probably not understanding you + not explaining myself properly. let me circle back: I hold an object with table names and other stuff. I need, for each table, to query its rows for example. How can I achieve that using msnodesqlv8? right now I'm looping through that object, getting the table name into some variable and want to place that name inside a query.

Comment: So that brings us back to my original comment: *"Why do you want to do this?"* As you therefore haven't answered this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232803/discussion-between-matanyap-and-larnu).

Comment: Why is important to the problem, [edit] your question to explain why you *want/need* to do this; again this normally implies a design flaw.

Comment: You want to sync multiple identical tables between databases. There are many ways to do this. I've never heard of anyone doing it in node.js though there's no reason that wouldn't work. One method of syncing is called replication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15 although it is a DBA heavy exercise, its much more maintainable and reliable than rolling your own replication solution in node.js. How quickly do the tables need to be in sync? 1 second? 1 day?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid problem is, one DB is using MSSQL and another is using MySQL. I know it's messy but that's the job I was given, there are clients involved and I can't mod anything. As for your question, it should happened at least every few minutes

Comment: I would suggest a Google of something like [Sync data between SQL Server and MySQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sync+data+between+SQL+Server+and+MySQL); there are plenty of existing questions and answers out there on this. If you get stuck, then you'll likely be better off on [dba.se] rather than [so]; depending on the question and where you get stuck implementing one of the solutions.

Comment: This is why it is important to tell the full story up front. Can you edit your question and add this information. There is no mention of MySQL anywhere in your question.

Comment: You'll need to decide whether you pay for a third party tool or pay to built a bespoke node.js replication solution.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've already managed to make the MySQL -> MSSQL direction work, I'm just trying to modify it to work in the other direction. BTW I didn't provide the whole story because I wanted to ask something specific and small, for it to maybe fit in the future for other people looking for the same thing in another frame

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. In answer to your original question, you need to concatenate the table name to the string `ql.query("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE someField = 2")` but you need to be **very** careful to protect against SQL injection... and of course taken in the bigger context, this is probably not a recommended way to approach this but if you have it working that's great